# How to set default encoding for existing files in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, encoding, cyrillic

There is an old C++ solution with a lot of files encoded with cp-1251. When opened from Solution Explorer or Code Definition Window, it is incorrectly displayed as cp-1252 file and all Russian comments become unreadable.

There is a way to open these files correctly: right-click from Solution Explorer, Open With, select editor with encoding. However it is very tedious and does not survive IDE exit.

Is there a way to permanently set an encoding to use when opening such files? Solution/project-wide solution will be ok as well as system-wide one.

**Edit**: one can make "Source code editor with encoding" the default editor for e.g. C++ files; that makes opening new files require a little less mouse work but does not eliminate the need to choose encoding manually each time.

Comment: What if you open the file with the right encoding and make small changes to the file, to force it to save the file with the right encoding.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: This does not help unfortunately. The next time I open this file, I have to use Open With Encoding again. Files have to stay cp-1251, and Visual Studio does not remember that.

Comment: I see, it is not easy. I have English settings, I had to use notepad to create a new file, add Russian text and save as utf-16, then rename the file to cpp file and add to project. The font has to be Russian compatible as well.

Answer (score 2):

If the files have to stay cp-1251,

- For viewing, change the default code-page of windows:
  "Settings" -> "Region" -> "Administrative" tab -> "[Language for non-Unicode programs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnste/2011/11/09/user-locale-system-locale-ui-language-language-profile-all-that/)"
- For compiling, try the compiler option "[/source-charset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt708819.aspx)"

Comment: In my case I had installed Russian language and some special characters were switched to Russian. It probably switched this setting to Russian. So I had there Russian, and after setting this to English and restarting Windows, everything is back to normal.

Also I knew it is my local problem, because in GIT there were no changes regarding Russian language.